# How to bring back the minimal context menu in firefox 25.0 (debian squeeze)?

Tags: firefox

Recently , I installed Firefox in Debian. (*I replaced the default Iceweasel with Firefox 25.0 from  Linux Mint's Debian package repo* )

Now ,when I right click , I get this enormous context menu.In  Iceweasel it was minimal.I want the  context menu to offer limited set of choices as default.How I can achieve this ?

[image]

These are details of my Linux distro :

> ```
> LSB Version:  core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch
> Distributor ID:   Debian
> Description:  Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.8 (squeeze)
> Release:  6.0.8
> Codename: squeeze
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **Menu Editor** add-on from [mozdev.org](http://menueditor.mozdev.org/). Head to preference button within add-ons manager:

[image]

Then tick whichever options you need in the context menu :

[image]

Now you'll get a clean and short context menu :

[image]